# One SSD cache for two partitions on two separate disks?

Tags: lvm, cache

I have two hard drives: one for my operating system and the other for other data. I recently bought an SSD drive that I would like to use an LVM cache for those two devices.

The problem is that I would like to keep data on those **two** drives **separate** in case of a failure, but at the same time make them use the same SSD drive as cache, most preferably without splitting the cache in half. Is there a way I could do that?

Comment: I don't understand this. Why don't you use the SSD for the OS? Then the OS can benefit from the speed of the SSD, and cache can be kept on the same disk. Why would the data disk need cache? Hybrid drives use a small SSD drive for caching, but that needs to be built into the drive.

Comment: My understanding is that a LVM cache can only cache one LVM partition. I could be wrong. So you need two LVM caches.

Comment: This looks very similar to [this]. [this]: https://superuser.com/questions/952016/how-can-i-use-one-lvmcache-cache-pool-lv-for-multiple-origin-lvs